# Set autonumber field?

Tags: c#, ms-access, dao

I have the following code which throws an exception "COM Exception was unhandled" in the line I set the attribute:

```
var tbdefinition = dbase.TableDefs["MyDB"];
var field_auid = tbdefinition.Fields["myColumn"];
field_auid.Attributes = 4;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to step through it or catch the exception?  Maybe it will give you more detail.

Comment: Use the debugger and see if that exception has an `InnerException` that gives more info. Are you sure `4` is a valid value here? And please explain (edit the question) what this has to do with an autonumber field.

Comment: Sorry for that, 4 is the number of an enum VBA value which sets the autoNumber attribute to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jet Databases, you cannot change the type of an existing field to Autonumber, if the table already contains records.
However, you can add a new field, which is an Autonumber field.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response but it took me a few hours to setup my new system at home.
Thanks for making that clear @Olivier.
The reason I turned to DAO was that I found out that the field wasn't ALTER ing to AutoNumber when I executed an OledbCommand ALTER command. Which is strange because it did the trick for another table I created. My database has 2 tables where the one has a foreign key to the other's primary key. Lets call them Parent and Child for ease of the following explanation of my code.

Comment: 1) Creating Parent1 and setting the PK. Then using DAO I set a BIT field as a checkbox and the fill the table from a DataSet which holds records of Parent + records of another copy of the same database with different data.
2) Creating Child2 in a similar manner.
3) ALTER ing the tables Fields that I want set as AutoNumber.
4) Dropping tables Parent and Child and renaming Parent1 to Parent and Child1 to Child. 
5) Finally I add the FK to the Child table.

Comment: Couple of weird things. My Parent's Field successfully alters to AutoNumber but my Child's doesn't. Well, it actually does! But it seems that when I rename the table from Child1 to Child it loses the attribute.